# app_offline.htm won't help on web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

We are using rsync to promote site content `(asp.net)` to different storages and we use `app_offline.htm` file before promotion to disable site. Unfortunately this solution doesn't work on `web.config` file which sometimes cannot be updated and `rsync` throws `rsync: rename failed for "<sitepath>/Web.config" (from .~tmp~/Web.config): Permission denied (13)`. We had similar issues with `.dll` files and that's why we use `app_offline`, but for `web.config` it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea what might cause it and how to fix it?

Comment: `app_offline.htm` doesn't help on _files_, it won't take your application "offline"; its just preventing requests to the Application and returns some predefined content. The Application is still running.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. App_offline doesn't change anything, it is just a file IIS will serve if present.

Comment: Maybe I should describe it more detailed. Without app_offline.htm IIS was opening a handle on dll files and these files cannot be updated/deleted during promotion(rsync transfer). When app_offline is present it preventing it as all requests are redirected to app_offline content. But still during the content transfer web.config file cannot be updated.

Comment: Are you able to **delete** the web.config while the app is running?

Comment: Yes, I can delete it manually. These sites are constantly pinged by users, but I can delete web.config, but rsync can't. Maybe it isn't related to IIS, but can't see any other reason it cannot be updated.

Comment: Don’t rely on ASP.NET offline mode. Bring the server out of its cluster and stop IIS. Then you can update contents, start IIS, and then put it back to the cluster.